# Log4j debug messages not going to IntelliJ console

Tags: intellij-idea, log4j, log4j2

I've got a springboot app using log4j2, and I cannot get logger.debug() messages to go to the console. I've added a log4j2.xml file (below) and am specifying the path to it in my VM options.. but its still not working. Am I missing something?  Using log4j 2.17.1.

```
-Dlog4j2.configurationFile=/Users/home/log4j2.xml
```

and

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="debug">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

The following code block...

```
logger.info("Test info.")
logger.debug("Test Debug.")
logger.warn("Test warn.")
logger.error("Test error.")
```

results in the following console output

```
2023-02-15 11:34:02.322  INFO 27001 --- [app] c.b.HelloWorld   : Test info.
2023-02-15 11:34:02.322  WARN 27001 --- [app] c.b.HelloWorld   : Test warn.
2023-02-15 11:34:02.322 ERROR 27001 --- [app] c.b.HelloWorld   : Test error.
```

Comment: [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would help a lot to understand the problem.

Comment: `logger.info()` and `logger.error()` statements get sent to the console.  `logger.debug()` do not

Comment: Please share a GitHub link for the complete sample project.